# Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation VB web service

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services

I am trying to create a simple VB web service in visual studio 2010, a music playlist service.

I had tried to create a function to check if a user exists in the DB but I am getting the error 'Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation' when running the program.

Here is the code for the client login form which calls the checkUser function, this is where the error seems to occur.

```
Dim service As New musicPlaylistService.Service1SoapClient("Service1Soap")
Public signinName As String
Dim check As Boolean

Private Sub signInBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles signInBtn.Click
    If signInNick.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a user name")
        signInNick.Focus()
    Else
        signinName = signInNick.Text
        main.Visible = True
        Me.Hide()
        main.tbxUserName.Text = signInNick.Text
        check = service.checkUser(signInNick.Text)
        If check = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("User has been created")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Thankyou for Signing In ", signInNick.Text)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

This is the code for the service checkUser function

```
'checking if user exists in the system already
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function checkUser(ByVal signinName As String) As String
    Dim numrows As Integer
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=MARTIN-LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=musicPlaylist;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE userNick = ('" & signinName & "')"
    conn.Open()
    Dim objcmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    numrows = objcmd.ExecuteScalar()

    If numrows > 0 Then
        getExistingUserPLData(signinName)
        Return True
    Else
        createUser(signinName)
        Return False
    End If

End Function
```

When running the program and I attempt to enter a username the error Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'checkUser'. is highlighted at the

```
 check = service.checkUser(signInNick.Text)
```

line of the code.

When clicking on view detail of the error message under inner exception i can see the message 'There is an error in XML document (1, 325)' and also 'The string 'True' is not a valid Boolean value'

Any help or assistance would be much appreciated,

thanks

Comment: Please narrow down the scope of your question by creating a reduced test case, which still produces the same issue, but works in an isolated environment (ideally it should have no dependencies). We should be able to reproduce the issue by copy-pasting your code into a brand new project.

Comment: Hi, I have now fixed the issue above, however I have encountered another issue. In the Private Sub signInBtn_Click code there is a variable check which is of type boolean which should get a value from checkUser function in the service. However it keeps getting the value true, even when it should not

Comment: Great! Please update your original question and include only the details relevant to the new question. Alternatively, you can post your solution as an answer, accept it, and then post another question.